# Check if page added To iPhone homescreen

Tags: javascript, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

Is it possible to check using JavaScript or CSS if a page has been added to the iPhone homescreen in webapp mode. Like getting the height of the screen which wouldn't have the nav bar so would be 460px

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for `window.navigator.standalone` (mentioned by [Apple here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW1))

This won't tell you if the page has been added to the homescreen if it is being visited in the regular browser, but it will tell you if it has been launched from the homescreen.

Comment: Is there a way to know if the page has been added to the homescreen from the regular browser?  Also, can the user be redirected to the webapp?